# Oracle TimeStamp Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to subtract Time in two dates. For example, I have 15:32:34 as sign_out date and 13:34:21 as sign_in date, now I want to do sign_out - sign_in with DATE data type, but I am unable to do it, I am getting 0 value for days, but I need to get the difference of time, can any one help me please

Comment: Please show some data, your current query and its output, and your desired output. Are the fields `date` or `timestamp`, as you mention both? What do you want the results to be - a number, an interval, a string...?

Comment: Hello Alex Poole my intention is to show the Sum of all intervals....in a string format. I declared the datatype as timestamp

Comment: Those aren't dates, they're times... as there's no "time" datatype you must be doing something slightly different than you state.

Comment: Hello Ben, here is the thing, i took sign_out sign_in as two timestamp values, and their values are '2014-04-24 13:56:21' and '2014-04-24 09:34:21' for student #1, and also the for the same student #1 other values are '2014-04-26 14:56:23' and '2014-04-26 12:33:21', now I want to calculate the total number of hours the student spent by adding the total hours on 2014-04-24 and 2014-04-26.Can u please let me know how to do that

Comment: Are they timestamps or dates @Karthik... you've said they're both and it changes the answer.

Comment: They are timestamps @Ben. I dont know how to send photo here, otherwise I would have sent it, No ben they are Timestamps not dates.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns are `timestamp` then the difference between them will be an interval. For the values you added as a comment:

```
select id, time_out - time_in as worked
from t42;

        ID WORKED    
---------- -----------
         1 0 4:22:0.0  
         1 0 2:23:2.0
```

You want the total, but you can't directly `sum` intervals. You could convert them to a numeric representation, sum them, and then convert them back:

```
select id, numtodsinterval(sum(
  extract(day from dd) * (24 * 60 * 60)
    + extract(hour from dd) * (60 * 60)
    + extract(minute from dd) * 60
    + extract(second from dd)
  ), 'SECOND') as total_worked
from (
  select id, time_out - time_in as dd
  from t42
)
group by id;

        ID TOTAL_WORKED
---------- ------------
         1 0 6:45:2.0
```

You could also treat them as dates; it isn't entirely clear if you're using fractional seconds but for this kind of data it would seem like unnecessary precision. I'm not sure why you aren't using `date` columns here (perhaps you just didn't realise that an Oracle `date` column does contain the time down to the second anyway?). Anyway, you can cast them to dates:

```
select id,
  sum(cast(time_out as date) - cast(time_in as date)) as total_days,
  numtodsinterval(sum(cast(time_out as date) - cast(time_in as date)), 'DAY')
    as total_interval,
  to_char(trunc(sysdate)
      + sum(cast(time_out as date) - cast(time_in as date)), 'HH24:MI:SS')
    as total_string
from t42
group by id;

        ID TOTAL_DAYS TOTAL_INTERVAL TOTAL_STRING
---------- ---------- -------------- ------------
         1 .281273148 0 6:45:2.0     06:45:02
```

[The result of subtracting two dates is a number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208), where 1 would be a whole day. I've shown two ways to convert that to something more useful.

The `to_char` version will only work if the total is less than a day though; if it might exceed 24 hours then you'd need to calculate it a different way:

```
select id,
  trunc(dd * 24) as hh,
  trunc((dd - (trunc(dd * 24)/24)) * 24 * 60) as mi,
  trunc((dd - trunc(dd * 24 * 60)/(24 * 60)) * (24 * 60 * 60)) as ss
from (
  select id,
    sum(cast(time_out as date) - cast(time_in as date)) as dd
  from t42
  group by id
);

        ID         HH         MI         SS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          6         45          1
```

... and you can concatenate those into a string if you want (with `lpad` to add leading zeros). It's odd that the 'seconds' value here is shown as 1, since `(dd - trunc(dd * 24 * 60)/(24 * 60)) * (24 * 60 * 60)` is 2, and `trunc(2)` is 2; not sure if there's a rounding error going on in their somewhere. If you use `round` instead of `trunc` in the final clasue then it works, but might give a slightly higher value than expected if you do have fractions of seconds.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d6b2/1), which doesn't show intervals in a very friendly format, unfortunately. That's with your sample, and another ID that does exceed 24 hours so you can see the difference; and with both `round` and `trunc` for the seconds in the last query.

Comment: Awesome Alex Poole....Also Final One Can u let me now how to convert seconds in NUMBER type into HH:MM:SS in oracle10g

Comment: it wrks Alex, in result I am getting more zeros before time like +000000000 4:32:43.20, can u let me know how to overcome that please ?

Comment: @KarthikAchanta - you can't really change the way the intervals are displayed - the client seems to decide that, and there isn't an equivalent of NLS_DATE_FORMAT to make it adjustable. If you need to format them then use the `cast` option (if the elapsed time is less than 24 hours), or `extract` the elements and concatenate them into a string.